# How do I get this Cisco VPN client to connect?

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, vpn, cisco

I've got Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit and installed network-manager-vpnc and configured the connection but I keep getting this:

```
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc'...                                                   
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 4420       
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' appeared, activating connections                              
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1                                                                                     
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3                                                                                     
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN connection 'CSI' (Connect) reply received.                                                                  
modem-manager: (net/tun0): could not get port's parent device                                                                                
NetworkManager[1217]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)                                 
NetworkManager[1217]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
kernel: [ 2281.723506] tun0: Disabled Privacy Extensions                                                                                     
avahi-daemon[1109]: Withdrawing workstation service for tun0.                                                                                
NetworkManager[1217]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)                               
NetworkManager[1217]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1                                                                                            
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 6                                                                                     
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0                                                                               
NetworkManager[1217]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.                    
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.                                              
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc'...                                                   
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 4547       
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' appeared, activating connections                              
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1                                                                                     
NetworkManager[1217]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
```

I've seen a couple of bugs on Launchpad that could be the same thing or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install [vpnc](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vpnc)
   package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vpnc
   ```
2. Create the connect script, copy the contents below into a file called vpn-connect and place it on the path somewhere:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   sudo vpnc --local-port 0 --enable-1des /etc/vpnc/vpn.conf
   ```
3. Copy over the .pcf file used by the Windows Cisco VPN client and use this as a basis for step 4.
4. Now you need to create the vpn.conf file in the /etc/vpnc directory. The content of this file are as follows:

   ```
   IPSec ID <your ipsec id>
   IPSec gateway <your gateway address>
   IPSec secret <your ipsec secret>

   Xauth username <your username>
   Xauth password <your password>
   IKE Authmode psk
   ```

   `<your username>` and `<your password>` should be obvious.

You now have everything required to connect, so run the script:

```
vpn-connect
```

After a few seconds it should come back with the message:

```
VPNC started in background
```

And give you a process id.

You should now be connected to the VPN.

Comment: Thanks for the help but since I asked the question I got a new job (yea!) so I really don't need to get this working.

Comment: @WebWeasel You can still mark it as an answer :P

Comment: The correct option is `--enable-1des`.

Answer (score 3):

I found that in my case the plugin was failing because vpnc was not happy about the encryption method

```
peer selected (single) DES as "encryption" method.
This algorithm is considered too weak today
If your vpn concentrator admin still insists on using DES
use the "--enable-1des" option.
```

This message could be only discovered by stracing the vpnc process.

In order to add `--enable-1des` option to vpnc command line I performed the following:

```
sudo -s
mv /usr/sbin/vpnc /usr/sbin/vpnc.real
cat <<EOF > /usr/sbin/vpnc
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/sbin/vpnc.real --enable-1des $*
EOF
chmod +x /usr/sbin/vpnc
```

Basically I replaced the vpnc binary with a wrapper script that supplied the necessary parameter.

Now NetworkManager VPNC plugin can connect properly.